# ¿Como compilar c y c++ en Atom?

Tags: c++, c, atom-editor

Acabo de instalar Atom en Windows 10 y tras haber añadido el paquete de gcc compiler me salta el error:

```
'gcc' could not be spawned. Is it installed and on your path? If so please open an issue on the package spawning the process.
```

EDICION:
He seguido el enlace que un OP ha añadido en comentarios y lo he conseguido instalar sin problema. Sin embargo, ahora lo compilo y salta en el terminal el siguiente mensaje:

```
no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
```

Por otra parte tengo instalado el antivirus Panda y creo detecta el archivo como un virus porque salta una notificacion diciendo que lo ha eliminado.

Comment: Es por las variables de entorno que no esta seteadas para que puedas compilar tu programa desde la consola. En este link te lo explica, https://platzi.com/tutoriales/1469-algoritmos/1901-como-instalar-gcc-para-compilar-programas-en-c-desde-la-consola-en-windows/

Comment: No edites la pregunt con la respuesta. Escribe una respuesta y la marcas como aceptada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando el [enlace](https://platzi.com/tutoriales/1469-algoritmos/1901-como-instalar-gcc-para-compilar-programas-en-c-desde-la-consola-en-windows/) que ha añadido un usuario en los comentarios se ha conseguido instalarlo sin problemas.

Es recomendable leer los comentarios de esa web porque para Windows 10 hay un apartado en el que es un poco distinto, pero es fácil de seguir.

Por otra parte, al tener instalado un antivirus, es posible que detecte los programas como virus o amenzas. En ese caso, habrá que configurar el antivirus.